# Can someone tell me which javascript techniques and libraries are involved in making pages like in the provided links

Tags: javascript, graphics

[Eeepad transformer prime](http://eee.asus.com/eeepad/transformer-prime/features/)

[XPS UltraBook](http://www.dell.com/html/global/xps13/xps-13-ultrabook.html?c=ca&l=en&s=dhs)

I want to learn how to get these effect done and tie in video playback/Image swapping? with the scroll progression.

I am guessing they are using SVG for all the moving images and Canvas for objects with no momentum such as sparkling animations etc.

Comment: Both of those sites are awful, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here they are... it's using jQuery and some scrolling animations.

```
<script src="/html/eeepad/js/libs/pack.js"></script>
<script src="/html/eeepad/js/libs/jquery.ytplayer.js"></script>
<script src="/html/eeepad/js/albertlan/custompagescroll.js"></script>
<script src="/html/eeepad/js/albertlan/scrollanimate.js"></script>
<script src="/html/eeepad/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="/html/eeepad/js/transformer-prime.js"></script>
```

Call me a fanboy if you will, but I think a simple, uniform interface and minimalistic design trumps overcomplicated scrolling animations in your face: http://www.apple.com/ipad/